# How to Trigger a Task based on previous task status?

Tags: airflow

I have 4 tasks as shown below. I want Task D to be triggered even if Task C has Failed or Succeeded. However, Task C or Task D should not be triggered if Task A or Task B has failed.

I tried to use trigger rule = all_done for Task D but if Task B fails, it triggers Task D as well.

[image: dag]

Is there a way to accomplish this in  Airflow?

Comment: Can you please confirm that the flow for all 4 tasks is horizontal as you shown without option to parallel tasks? For example can Task_A and Task_B run in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, B is the critical task, and C is non-critical, but you want it to at least make an attempt before D.

First you need to remove all the trigger rules you have applied.

You currently have `all_done` on C, which means that C runs even when B fails -- which you don't want.

Next you need to add a dependency between B and D:

```py
task_b >> task_d
```

Now B and C are each *independently* upstream of D.

So what remains are two problems:

- D must not run if B fails
- D must not run until C is done

You can't do `one_success` because the important one is B and it's not enough if C alone succeeds.

What you need is "B success and C done".

A relatively clean way to do this is to make C "skip" instead of fail if an error is encountered.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```py
class MySkippingDummyOperator(DummyOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            super().execute(context)
        except Exception as e:
            raise AirflowSkipException(f'skipping instead of failing.')
```

If MySkippingDummyOperator encounters an error, the task will end in skipped state.

So B is success / fail, and C is success / skip.  With this behavior we can use trigger rule `none_failed` on task D.

`none_failed` means everything completed and nothing failed.

And this should produce the desired behavior:

- if B is unsuccessful, then D can't run
- if C is unsuccessful, it will only be a skip, so D can still run
- D will not run unless both B and C are done

Alternatively, you could let D use `all_done`, and then from within D retrieve the task instance state of B and then skip D if B failed.  But this is more complicated and certainly more of a hack.